# Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate

Tags: phpmailer, google-workspace, bluehost

I'm trying to send messages using PHPMailer with a G Suite account email on Bluehost and can not figure out why it won't send.

This is the error I'm getting: Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Here is my PHP code:

```
public static function SendMail ($subject, $body, $alt_body, $to, $from, $reply_to = null)
{
    if (empty ($reply_to))
        $reply_to = $from;

    $mail = new PHPMailer (true);                               // Passing `true` enables exceptions

    try 
    {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                   // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                        // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'mydomain.com';                           // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                 // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'mymail@mydomain.com';                // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'mypassword';                         // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                              // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                                      // TCP port to connect to

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom ($from[key ($from)], key ($from));
        $mail->addAddress ($to[key ($to)], key ($to));          // Add a recipient
        $mail->addReplyTo ($reply_to[key ($reply_to)], key ($reply_to));

        //Content
        $mail->isHTML (true);                                   // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $body;
        $mail->AltBody = $alt_body;

        $mail->send();
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to enable less secure apps for it to work (I've encountered similar problems in Node & Rails apps). To do so: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: Enable debug output with `SMTPDebug = 2`, and then you'll be able to see what the server is saying. When you've done that, read the troubleshooting guide and then read answers on here that have answered the same question before.

Comment: Also, you say you're sending through gmail, but you have not set `Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'`.

Comment: @Synchro Yes, through gmail but I'm using G Suite to send and receive emails so MX records are for G Suite set up. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Will try setting SMPTDebug = 2

Comment: As far as I’m aware gsuite uses the same outbound configuration as gmail, though I may be mistaken. MX only affects inbound, so not relevant here.